# How can I play video, fullscreen, without keyboard and mouse interfering, on Linux

Tags: linux, video, media-player

I would like to pull a prank, which basically plays a pre-made video full-screen, so it looks like my actual computer

I would like to fake moving the mouse and typing stuff, but when I use something like VLC it does all sorts of actions and makes menus appear. So I would like a video player, which will not show anything when keyboard is being used or mouse is being moved, except for a few keyboard shortcuts that let me stop the video

I can't literally disable mouse and keyboard as devices (it's a laptop and I don't want softwares to disable them). It's fine if stuff like <kbd>Super</kbd>/<kbd>WinKey</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> still work, I just want to use the alphabet, space and enter

I'm running Linux Mint 18

### Edit:

[This](https://mpv.io/manual/master/) might do the trick, will try out when I get a chance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right about mpv, but you'll need to disable some common options so it behaves the way you want. What options you'll need will somewhat depend on your window manager/desktop environment, but here's the command that works for me:

`mpv --no-input-default-bindings --cursor-autohide=no --osc=no --fullscreen --on-all-workspaces your_video.mp4`

In short, here's what these options do (from left to right):

- Disable the keyboard shortcuts that normally let you control the video player
- Disable autohiding of your cursor. That is, make it so your cursor will always stay visible
- Disable the onscreen controller
- Start mpv in fullscreen
- Play the video on all workspaces

Be careful when executing the above command, since you obviously won't be able to close mpv by pressing q, which is the normal shortcut to quit. Keyshortcuts like Alt-F4 should still work though.